# Is there a way to count repeated strings in records from a MySQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if there is a way to count repeated strings in diferent records in a MySQL table, for instance, given a table like this one:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | data                  |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | this is here          |
+----+-----------------------+
|  2 | this would be nice    |
+----+-----------------------+
|  3 | this was here         |
+----+-----------------------+
|  4 | this needs to be said |
+----+-----------------------+
```

I'd like the following result:

```
Count: this(4), here(2)
```

This is what I've been looking for, but no luck until now.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried that isn't working as expected.

Comment: Why only those two words?

Comment: Those two are the only repeated, that's what I'm aiming. Counting only repeated strings part of the field content, not the whole field

Comment: So why not `be`?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this:

```sql
SELECT id, data, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,' ',x.x),' ',-1) as Y
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (select 1 as x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) x
ORDER BY id, x.x
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/PkMEYLy_)

output:

| id | data | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is here | this |
| 1 | this is here | is |
| 1 | this is here | here |
| 1 | this is here | here |
| 2 | this would be nice | this |
| 2 | this would be nice | would |
| 2 | this would be nice | be |
| 2 | this would be nice | nice |
| 3 | this was here | this |
| 3 | this was here | was |
| 3 | this was here | here |
| 3 | this was here | here |
| 4 | this needs to be said | this |
| 4 | this needs to be said | needs |
| 4 | this needs to be said | to |
| 4 | this needs to be said | be |

Things left to be done:

- Check If you have more, of less than, 4 words. Currently when you only have 3 word the last word is repeated, and when having more than 5 words they are ignored.
- Count the stuff, but that is basic SQL stuff using `count(*)`

BONUS: Getting the number of words in a string:

```sql
SELECT 
   id, 
   data, 
   length(data)-length(replace(data,' ',''))+1 as NrOfWords
from test;
```

output:

| id | data | NrOfWords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is here | 3 |
| 2 | this would be nice | 4 |
| 3 | this was here | 3 |
| 4 | this needs to be said | 5 |